Negative values in linear trend and Confidence interval in R
Firstly, the code used.
ggplot(correlation, aes(x=area_ha, y=extent_2000_ha)) 
+ geom_point( color="green") + theme_ipsum() 
+ theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=14)) 
+ scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})
+ scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)
+ geom_smooth(method=lm, color="red", se=FALSE) 

When I want to include the linear trend and the confidence interval (attached graphs), negative values appear on OY (-200.000). I must mention that all values are positive, no negative values.



The regression line starts with the first point in the x axis and that linear fit's intercept is negative. That's why the y axis extends to negative values. When you also plot the CI's, that effect is greater because the plot must accommodate for lower y values.

the lower graph also possesses a negative value on the Y-axis. you may hard to find it because the scale is in every 100,000. if you rescale the display to 50,000, -50,000 would appear below y=0.

If it only makes sense for your regression line to be strictly positive, then a standard linear regression is just not the right model for your data. A linear regression will simply find the line which minimizes the squared distances from your data to the line. It does not care if this means the line becomes negative where you think it shouldn't be. This is an extra constraint that you need to build into your model, and this is dependent on the context and phyical interpretation of your data (which we can only guess at from the information in your question).
For example, you  could consider a linear regression with a fixed intercept of 0:
ggplot(correlation, aes(x = area_ha, y = extent_2000_ha)) +
  geom_point( color = "green4", alpha = 0.2) + 
  theme_ipsum() + 
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=14)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma, limits = c(0, 8e5)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "red3", formula = y ~ x + 0,
              fullrange = TRUE, alpha = 0.2) 


Or perhaps a generalised linear model with a log-link function:
ggplot(correlation, aes(x = area_ha, y = extent_2000_ha)) +
  geom_point( color = "green4", alpha = 0.2) + 
  theme_ipsum() + 
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=14)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma, limits = c(0, 8e5)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", color = "red", method.args = list(family = poisson),
              fullrange = TRUE) 


As for which model is best, that is a statistics question rather than a programming question. It's therefore off-topic here, but may be on topic at CrossValidated.

Data used
There was no data included in the question, so I created a similar dataset from the following code to create the above examples
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

set.seed(2)
correlation <- data.frame(area_ha = runif(100, 1, 8e5))
correlation$extent_2000_ha <- (correlation$area_ha + 
                                 rnorm(100, 0, correlation$area_ha))^2/9e6
correlation <- correlation[correlation$extent_2000_ha > 1e4,]
correlation <- correlation[correlation$extent_2000_ha < 1e6,]
correlation <- round(correlation)

